# Prove: $f(x)^{p^k}\equiv f\left(x^{p^k}\right)\bmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$p$ is a prime number, $k$ is an positive integer, and $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$.

> Prove: $f(x)^{p^k}\equiv f\left(x^{p^k}\right)\bmod p$

Comment: Do you understand what you are being asked to prove? Are you unsure about the notation? Do you know what a prime number is? Do you know what a proof is? It is very difficult to know what you need help with given what you've written so far.

Comment: What is $f$? Please explain the context of this question (there has been some guessing about it going on below).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen hi, $f$ is intented to be element of $Z[x]$. Sorry, but your answer is also useful which remind me of the domain of $f$.

Comment: I've took the liberty to add that hypothesis to the question, so that it the question become a bit more readable. Actually there is still ambiguity whether the statement is a congruence in $\Bbb Z$ (as suggested by "$\pmod p$"; this is what I thought initially) or one in $\Bbb Z[x]$ (so it is about polynomial substitution, not evaluation; this is what I understand now, but it would be better so say "$\pmod{p\Bbb Z[x]}$").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Step One*: [Freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic) in characteristic $p$:

$$(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p$$

*Step Two*: $n$-ary version (induct on $n$):

$$(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^p\equiv a_1^p+\cdots+a_n^p$$

*Step Three*: Polynomial version ([little Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) on coefficients):

$$f(x)^p\equiv (a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)^p\equiv\cdots\cdots \equiv f(x^p)$$

*Step Four*: Arbitrary power version (induct on $k$):

$$f(x)^{p^k}\equiv f(x^{p^k}).$$

Comment: Which property of $f$ did you use, and where in the question was that property specified?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Obviously the problem is about ${\bf Z}[x]/(p)$.

Comment: I don't see why this is obvious at all (though the idea did come to my mind). Even with the (polynomials) tag, only integer-to-integer behaviour of the polynomial function is necessary for the statement to make sense (not of course to make it true). And as you can see in my answer, the much weaker hypothesis of compatibility with reduction modulo$~p$ does very nicely as well (and with less work). Mind reading of OPs is not my sport.

Comment: My impression is that a realistic context where the problem appears in a text would not shirk away from the concept of polynomial rings, and thus would be utilizing them here. The suggestion that understanding the original problem is an exercise in reading the OP's mind (who may or may not understand the problem, and certainly didn't invent it him or herself) seems odd to me.

Comment: Yes, assuming polynomial with integer coefficients allows for proving a useful result. Not assuming it only allows for nitpicking bullshit, which is what those that don't really have anything interesting to say but still have the urge to say something do. The counterexamples are trivial, the result is not and it is very useful too.

Answer (score 3):

This is **false**, unless you assume something about the function $f$ that you did not (assuming that it is a polynomial function with *integer* coefficients will do). As a simple counterexample, take $p=2$, $f(n)=\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$, $k=1$ and $x=3$, then $f(x)^p=3^2=9$ is odd while $f(x^p)=f(9)=36$ is even.

Since you assumed nothing at all about $f$, there are even simpler ways to get counterexamples. Take for $f$ the function that is $1$ at $x=3$ and $0$ everywhere else (in particular at $3^2=9$), again with $p=2$ and $k=1$.

Just in case an additional hypothesis on $f$ gets added to the question, I'll mention that the result is true for *any* function $f$ that is *compatible with reduction modulo$~p$*, in other words for which $x\equiv y\pmod p$ implies $f(x)\equiv f(y)\pmod p$. Then the result is simply a consequence of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) which states that $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ for all integers $a$. By iteration this implies $a^{p^k}\equiv a$ for all $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $k\in\Bbb N$, so that
$$
  f(x)^{p^k}\equiv f(x)\equiv f(x^{p^k}) \pmod p
$$
where the second congruence uses the supposed compatibility of$~f$ with reduction modulo$~p$ (in other words both instances of the powering become no-ops modulo$~p$ and the identity becomes trivial). Polynomials with integer coefficients have the required compatibility with modular reduction, while polynomials with rational coefficients do not always, even if they map integers to integers always.

**Added** after the hypothesis $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$ was added to the question. Okay, so I misread the question, and made myself look rather stupid. Forgive me for reading $f(x)$ as a function being applied to an arbitrary value$~x$, which is what it would mean on most occasions; the main point I missed is that $x$ is an *indeterminate* here. I will remember this as a most striking example of what is so bad about writing polynomials as $P(x)$.

So the question really is about an identity in $\def\Zp{\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z}(\Zp)[x]$, namely that raising any element to the power $p^k$ gives the same result as substituting $x^{p^k}$ for $x$. I would write this, using notation that I hope will be clear
$$
  Q^{p^k} = Q[x:=x^{p^k}] \qquad\text{for all $Q\in(\Zp)[x]$ and $k\in\Bbb N$.}
$$
To prove it, note first that a substitution $Q\mapsto Q[x:=a]$ always defines a *ring morphism*, in the current case $a=x^{p^k}$ an endomorphism of $(\Zp)[x]$. So a first concern is that the operation $Q\mapsto Q^{p^k}$ on the left should also be a ring morphism. This is the case, because $r\mapsto r^p$ for $r\in R$ is an endomorphism in any ring$~R$ of characteristic$~p$ (the [Frobenius endomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)), and we are considering the $k$-th power of that endomorphism.

Now since we are comparing two endomorphisms of $(\Zp)[x]$, it will suffice to check that the result holds for $Q$ running through a generating set of $(\Zp)[x]$, one from which all other elements can be obtained by addition and multiplication. The set $\{1,x\}$ is such a generating set, and the identity above obviously holds for $Q=1$ and for $Q=x$. (I should warn that although the proof might suggest that the result holds if one replaces $(\Zp)[x]$ by another ring$~R$ (for instance a finite field) of characteristic$~p$, this is not so, since $\{1,x\}$ will no longer be a generating set; indeed the identity requires the Frobenius endomorphism to be the identity on$~R$, and this *only* holds for $R=\Zp$.)

Comment: The idea here is that the problem statement is about reducing elements of polynomial rings mod $p$ (in particular integer-coefficient polynomials), rather than evaluating polynomials and *then* reducing mod $p$; while it is clear the first is what's going on here, it needs to be clear to the OP. Aside: OP's original post had the tag `(polynomials)` which I deleted because it didn't seem relevant enough.

Comment: @anon: The statement clearly asks for a congruence mod$~p$ between the _results_ of evaluating $f$ (and taking a power of it on the left). The fact that, if you only want to know the result mod$~p$, you can reduce (the coefficients of) the polynomial itself before evaluating may be useful in the proof, but I don't see how the problem _statement_ involves that. The fact that $f$ induces a well defined function $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ seems a key property to me (it is what makes $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$ work), but it is not part of the problem statement either.

Comment: @anon: Now the question is edited, I understand your comment. My comment above shows that I didn't understand before: for me $f(\ldots)$ suggested function evaluation, possibly polynomial evaluation, but not polynomial _substitution_.