# Proving $f(x)^p \equiv f(x^p) \bmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove the statement in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469746/prove-fxpk-equiv-f-leftxpk-right-bmod-p) for the case $k=1$ in detail, i.e. I'm trying to prove that $f(x)^p \equiv f(x^p) \bmod p$ for $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $p$ a prime number (I have read the first answer given in that post, and am trying to fill in the details).

Let $f(X) := \sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$. By the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), we get that
\begin{align}
f(X)^p = \sum_{k_0+\ldots+k_n=p} \binom{p}{k_0,\ldots,k_n}\prod_{j=0}^n(a_jX^j)^{k_j}
= \sum_{j=0}^na_jX^{jp} + \sum_{ \substack{k_0+\ldots+k_n=p \\ k_0,\ldots,k_n\neq0} } \binom{p}{k_0,\ldots,k_n}\prod_{j=0}^n (a_jX^j)^{k_j}. \tag1
\end{align}
Define
$$
S(X) := \sum_{ \substack{k_0+\ldots+k_n=p \\ k_0,\ldots,k_n\neq0} } \binom{p}{k_0,\ldots,k_n}\prod_{j=0}^n (a_jX^j)^{k_j}.
$$
Then, because
$$
a_j^pX^{jp} - (a_j^p-a_j)X^{jp} = a_jX^{jp},
$$
and with equation $(1)$, we see that
$$
f(X^p) = f(X)^p - S(X) - \sum_{j=0}^n(a_j^p-a_j)X^{jp}.
$$
Next, we note that $p \vert S(X)$ because of the condition $k_0,\ldots,k_n\neq0$, and so $p \vert \binom{p}{k_0,\ldots,k_n}$. Moreover, $p\vert(a_j^p-a_j)$ for all $j$, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), so we know that $p$ divides the expression
$$
- S(X) - \sum_{j=0}^n(a_j^p-a_j)X^{jp}, \tag2
$$
so we can write $(2)$ as $pg(X)$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Finally, we can write $f(X^p) = f(X)^p + pg(X) \iff f(X)^p = f(X^p) - pg(X)$, hence we get the result $f(X)^p \equiv f(X^p) \bmod p$.

My question: Is this a rigorous proof, or am I missing something? I am asking, because using the multinomial theorem is too messy for my taste. Cheers!

Comment: Looks complicated. Why can't you just use $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ ?

Comment: @PM2Ring well I used it to show that equation $(2)$ is divisible by $p$. I'm not sure where you'd use this theorem.

Comment: $f(x)^p\equiv f(x)\pmod p$ and in general if $x$ is coprime to $p$ $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$